# View plain response (from HTTPS) in WireShark

Tags: wireshark

I couldn't find exact answer.
In similar topics, people say that without Private key you can't view HTTPS response, but I am surprised, why key needed at all? For example, when browser requests [`https://example.com`](https://example.com), it can read view it's html output.

And I want the same in WireShark (one of my program reads response from `https://example.com` and want to view just that page's outputed HTML). However, I can't understand why Private key is needed with this simple task?

Comment: The entire point of using HTTPS is to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. Why should Wireshark be special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't need to know the private key, an attacker wouldn't need it either – then any HTTPS traffic including login information, credit card numbers, photos, etc could be read by anybody that is on the same network as you (somebody listening to wi-fi traffic), or anywhere between you and the server (ISPs). This would be a disaster.

HTTPS (or more specifically TLS) was created for this purpose – to be able to communicate with remote parties securely without having complete trust in every single node on the way to the remote party. It relies on public-key cryptography, which makes it so that it is easy to encrypt messages with the public key, but extremely difficult (or practically impossible) to reverse the encryption without knowing the private key.

A browser which communicates with a server via HTTPS creates a link based on keys exchanged securely. Only the server and the browser know these keys, and so only the server and the browser can send and receive messages to each other.

Wireshark, even if it is running on your computer, is not running as a part of your browser and hence does not know the keys that the server and the browser agreed on. So it is impossible for it to read the traffic.

It may be somewhat surprising to know that even if somebody (Wireshark) can read all the data your browser exchanges with a server, it will not know the keys that the browser and server agreed on.

> Traditionally, secure encrypted communication between two parties required that they first exchange keys by some secure physical channel, such as paper key lists transported by a trusted courier. The Diffie–Hellman key exchange method allows two parties that have no prior knowledge of each other to jointly establish a shared secret key over an insecure channel. This key can then be used to encrypt subsequent communications using a symmetric key cipher.
>
> [Diffie-Hellman key exchange, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

Comment: so, let's say, `c#` application sends request to url `https://example.com`, is not it possible for wireshark, to detect what URL is being requsted by that program? Then I could just open that url myself in browser.

Comment: @T.Todua See here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/does-ssl-tls-https-hide-the-urls-being-accessed tl;dr: from the traffic you could potentially find out the hostname of the request, but not the specific URL (so `https://example.com/`, but not `https://example.com/somepage`).

Comment: Well, maybe I missed important part in question. I want to track program on my computer, not other computers in network. Doesnt it make a difference? Can't I see  my  XYZ (c#)  application calls to which urls and gets what response? or it's same hard as if i were tracking other pc in network?  thanks in advance

Comment: @T.Todua Well no, it doesn't make a big difference. What Wireshark sees is just your browser interacting with the server. If you were on a wired connection, you would see the exact same communication running Wireshark on a different computer on the same network. You could make a difference by intentionally building a browser which leaks its private keys, e.g. getting the Chromium source code and adding debug print output for HTTPS communication … But, this is a huge hobby project of its own and I can't really advise you (I haven't done it myself).

Comment: I wish i could upvote your comments too:) thanks. btw, integrate them in answer, will be better